# Plugin for Solr Suggester Component

Tags: solr, autocomplete, lucene, search-suggestion

I created a plugin for Solr (version 6.3) that adds a permission layer to filter the retrieved documents using a database query (e.g: the user with ID 2 hasn't permissions to see the document with the ID 1); As the logic that defines if an user has permissions needs fields that aren't indexed in the Solr, i need to check in the database.

To achieve that i created a Query Parser (called `DocumentsByUserParser` that extends the class `QParserPlugin`) defined in the solrconfig.xml with the following:

`<queryParser name="filterDocument" class="mypackage.solr.plugin.DocumentsByUserParser" />`

To call this plugin, i only have to set the `fq` parameter with the `{!filterDocument userId='<user_id>'}` along with the other query parameters. Note that the code above works well with the Search Component with an edismax type.

---

My question is: can i create a new similar plugin, as described above, that works with the **Suggest Component**? Because when I index a document, the user may have (or not) permissions to see that document, so the suggester shouldn't show suggestions that the user hasn't permissions to see.

I defined my Suggest Component along with the Request Handler with the following:

```
<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
   <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="suggest">true</str>
      <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
   </lst>
   <arr name="components">
      <str>suggest</str>
   </arr>
</requestHandler>

<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
   <lst name="suggester">
       <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
       <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
       <str name="indexPath">suggester_infix_dir</str>
       <str name="highlight">true</str>
       <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
       <str name="field">AUTO_COMPLETE_FIELD</str>
       <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
       <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
       <str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
   </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

P.S - The context filter query described in https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/suggester.html only works with a single **indexed** field, so this will not work with my use case.